# Conditional expected value variable change

Tags: statistics, random-variables, conditional-expectation, expected-value

Assume that we have $X_1,X_2,X_3$ that are jointly Gaussian, $E(X_i)=0$ and with non-zero covariances. We also have:

$$Y_1=X_1$$

$$Y_2=X_2−X_1$$

$$Y_3=X_3−X_2$$

With $0$ covariances among all $Y_i$ and $E(Y_i^2)=1$

Is the following operation valid:

$$E(Y_3^2|X_1,X_2)=E(Y_3^2|Y_1,Y_2)=E(Y_3^2)=1$$

Also consider: $$E(Y_3^2|X_1,X_2)= E(X_3^2|X_1,X_2)-2E(X_3|X_1,X_2)X_2-X_2^2$$
Which should be impossible to solve with the current information.

I know that in the case of jointly gaussian variables a correlation of $0$ implies independence and all $X_i$ are jointly gaussian but does this property extend to all the $Y_i$?

Comment: You can get proper spacing for conditional probabilities by using `\mid` instead of `|`.

Comment: I am sorry, that property indeed is wrong, I have so many notes in here that i get confused, the covariances are non zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your argument is correct. An affine (in this case: linear) transformation of jointly Gaussian variables again yields jointly Gaussian variables; see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Affine_transformation). Since fixing $X_1$ and $X_2$ is equivalent to fixing $Y_1$ and $Y_2$, the first equality holds, and since the $Y_i$ are jointly normal with zero covariance, the second equality holds.

Comment: But how can it be that if $$E(Y_3^2|X_1,X_2)= E(X_3^2|X_1,X_2)-X_2^2$$. There must be a fallacy somewhere

Comment: @OscarGarcia: How did you get that equation?

Comment: From $Y3=X3−X2$
Ah I forgot to mention a property, also $E(X_i)=0 and E(X_i,X_j)=0$.

The original problem had more things but I needed to cut them down since people were not respongin to a large post but I will edit it

Comment: @OscarGarcia: From $Y_3=X_3-X_2$ we have $Y_3^2=\left(X_3-X_2\right)^2=X_3^2-2X_3X_2+X_2^2$. I don't see how that leads to what you wrote, even with $E\left(X_i\right)=0$. Did you replace $(X_3-X_2)^2$ by $X_3^2-X_2^2$?

Comment: Ah, it seems I was confused with something, I will rewrite the equation but the point stands that $E(X_3^2|X_1,X_2)$ and $E(X_3|X_1,X_2)$ should be unsolvable

Comment: I just don't get how can it be possible that $Y_3$ ignore the given values of $X_1,X_2$ when $X_3$ is clearly not independent of them. It would imply that no matter what value these variables take it makes no difference to $Y_3$. I don't buy, something somewhere must be wrong.

Comment: I really hate stack overflow not allowing me to edit questions:
$X_3$ is dependent then I don't see why the values of $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not affecting $Y_3$

Comment: @OscarGarcia: I'm afraid I don't understand where you see a problem here. $Y_3$ and $X_3$ are completely different variables. Why shouldn't it be possible that $Y_3$ is independent of $X_1$ and $X_2$ whereas $X_3$ isn't?

Comment: Ok, I will give a counter example:
$X_1=a, X_2=\infty$
Then:
$E(X_3^2|X_1,X_2)-2E(X_3|X_1,X_2)X_2-\infty=1$

how can it be?

Comment: How is it possible that $Y_3$ being a function of $X_3$ and a constant ($X_2$) behaves independently when $X_3$ is not independent

Comment: @OscarGarcia: You still have the wrong sign on $X_2^2$; as I wrote above, it's $+X_2^2$. Unfortunately I still don't see the problem. Why shouldn't the other two terms in the equation also go to $\infty$ and make it come out right? $X_3$ isn't independent of $X_2$, so specifying $X_2\to\infty$ can make its expectation (or that of its square) go to $\infty$.

Comment: You cannot rest infinities like that, it is indeterminate. Having an infinity in there guarantees that it will never equal 1, therefore something must be wrong. (If I could edit the comment I would do it but it makes no difference to my argument)

Comment: @OscarGarcia: That's not a proper argument. You wrote $=\infty$ and I indulged you so as not to waste time on technicalities. Note that I wrote more rigorously in terms of going to $\infty$, as $\infty$ is not a possible value of $X_2$. I don't see anything in your arguments that precludes $X_2$ and the corresponding conditional expectations of $X_3$ and $X_3^2 $ from jointly going to $\infty$ in such a manner that the equation is always fulfilled and the left-hand side always comes out to $1$.

Comment: @OscarGarcia: By the way, if there were a problem with indeterminacies due to infinities (there isn't), it would have nothing to do with dependence or independence; you could make the same invalid argument to show that $E\left(A\mid X_1,X_2\right)$ can't take any value at all, for any $A$, simply by subtracting out $X_2$ and creating spurious cancelling infinities.

Comment: Only $X_2$ appears directly on the equation. If we fix $X_2=a$ how come $X_1$ can take any value and the equation will always in some magical way evaluate to 1 and only because it happens to be jointly gaussian (or this does not work). $X_3$ is not independent but for some reason behaves in a way that it's value does not seem to matter.

Comment: I give up statistics, this is all made up. I will just focus on real world problems that I can solve with algorithms were this kind of cases with ultra specific conditions that result in wonderland situations that will never come close to happen in meat space.

The original problem had the rule $E(X_i,X_j)=min(i,j)$ for $i \neq j$ (from where all the math of the $Y$s is derived). Which, if you ask me, is ludicrous.

Comment: @OscarGarcia: There really is nothing theoretical or strange or magical about it. This could come up in a real-life example. There's no "only" in "because it happens to be jointly Gaussian". That's what having a joint distribution and not being independent means – that the values are correlated. I suggest you write up some code that actually generates these variables and observe how things work out.

Comment: @OscarGarcia: "$X_3$ is not independent but for some reason behaves in a way that it's value does not seem to matter." That's the wrong way around. Precisely because it's not independent it can behave that way. If it were independent, it couldn't, and it would then indeed be inexplicable how the $X_2$ term that goes to infinity could be compensated.

Comment: @OscarGarcia: OK, I think we can leave it at that. All the best to your mother :-)